# Python XML add element to file

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have about 1000 xml files, and some are missing an element.  I made a script to search through the xml's and print the element.  I wanted to add the ability to add the element if it isnt there, but am unsuccessful.

As you can see below, the DVT3 isnt there and it needs to be added.

My Code

```
XMLParser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    if f.endswith(".xml"):

        xmlfile = directory + '/' + f


        tree = etree.parse(xmlfile, parser=XMLParser)
        root = tree.getroot()

        hardwareRevisionNode = root.find(".//hardwareRevision")

        try:
            print f + ' :   ' + hardwareRevisionNode.text
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
            print xmlfile
            #Wearable = root.find(".//Wearable")
            ChildNode = etree.Element(".//Wearable")
            ChildNode.text = "DVT2"
            ChildNode.append(ChildNode)
            tree.write(xmlfile, pretty_print=True)
```

XML File

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<Speech>
  <Results>
    <breakpoint name="ASR_START_RECOGNITION" elapsedTime="00:00:00.000" />
  </Results>
  <Meta>
    <Dialog>
      <sessionUUID>7c9b1e3a-b22f-4793-818f-72bc6e7b84a9</sessionUUID>
    </Dialog>
    <ASR>
      <engine>
        <name>Rockhopper</name>
        <version>1.0.0.61</version>
      </engine>
      <wrapper>
        <name>RockhopperAsrEngine</name>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
      </wrapper>
      <wrapper>
        <name>Core</name>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
      </wrapper>
      <resource>
        <name>Language Model</name>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
      </resource>
    </ASR>
    <Application>
      <name>FightClub</name>
      <version>0.1.550</version>
      <commit>8f7a411</commit>
      <buildDate>2016-03-09T18:16Z</buildDate>
      <branch>HEAD</branch>
    </Application>
    <Wearable>
      <firmware>1.0.183 - FCB1APP000-1611W0183</firmware>
    </Wearable>
  </Meta>
</Speech>
```

XML file I Want

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<Speech>
  <Results>
    <breakpoint name="ASR_START_RECOGNITION" elapsedTime="00:00:00.000" />
  </Results>
  <Meta>
    <Dialog>
      <sessionUUID>7c9b1e3a-b22f-4793-818f-72bc6e7b84a9</sessionUUID>
    </Dialog>
    <ASR>
      <engine>
        <name>Rockhopper</name>
        <version>1.0.0.61</version>
      </engine>
      <wrapper>
        <name>RockhopperAsrEngine</name>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
      </wrapper>
      <wrapper>
        <name>Core</name>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
      </wrapper>
      <resource>
        <name>Language Model</name>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
      </resource>
    </ASR>
    <Application>
      <name>FightClub</name>
      <version>0.1.550</version>
      <commit>8f7a411</commit>
      <buildDate>2016-03-09T18:16Z</buildDate>
      <branch>HEAD</branch>
    </Application>
    <Wearable>
      <firmware>1.0.183 - FCB1APP000-1611W0183</firmware>
      <hardwareRevision>DVT3</hardwareRevision>
    </Wearable>
  </Meta>
</Speech>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can try out [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict).

```
import xmltodict as x

with open(myfile) as f:

    xmlDictionary=x.parse(f.read(),'utf-8')
    xmlDictionary['Speech']['Meta']['Wearable'].update({"hardwareRevision": "DVT3"})

    output = x.unparse(xmlDictionary)

    with open(outfile,'w') as out:
        out.write(output)
```

Make it run in parallel if you want, and if storage is a concern simply replace contents of files (or delete old ones immediatelly after new ones are made).